# Как вручную установить библиотеку Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, библиотеки, установка, poi

Такой вопрос - какие файлы и куда скачанной библиотеки Apache POI на Java надо ставить, что бы можно было работать не используя среды разработки, а просто через Notepad?

Comment: Какие файлы вы скачали и откуда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо скачать как минимум

poi-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
commons-collections4-4.2.jar

Положить их в любой удобный каталог и указывать его в ключе `-cp` при компиляции и выполнении. Например, если файлы скачаны в каталог C:\Temp

```
javac -cp C:\Temp\* Example.java
java -cp .;C:\Temp\* Example
```

Comment: а в самом коде указывать просто импорт необходимых библиотек как и с стандартными библиотеками Java?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Делаю импорт, а компилятор начинает ругаться
    import java.io.*;
    import poi-3.17;
    import xmlbeans-2.6.0;

    class exl {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  
 }
     }

пишет  error: '.' expected и так дальше по символам после import

Comment: После инструкции `import` следует имена пакетов, находящихся в jar-файлах, а не самих jar-файлов.

Comment: Вопрос по запуску. Сделал все как Вы сказали - компилятор проходит норм.Но при самом запуске java выдает 
E:\poi-3.17\* : Имя "E:\poi-3.17\*" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы
. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:12
+ java -cp .;E:\poi-3.17\*  exl
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:\poi-3.17\*:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Знаки ".;" при запуске java. Они для чего?

Comment: Точка обозначает текущий каталог, а точка с запятой - это разделитель путей в Windows. В Linux'ах вместо точки с запятой двоеточие.

Comment: А звёздочка - подстановочный символ для имени файла целиком, а не его части. Буквально означает "любой jar-файл в каталоге".

Comment: Я понял. Но а что с ошибкой то делать? Компиляция норм проходит, а при попытке запуска не видит этот файл.

Comment: Файл, что я компилирую и пытаюсь запустить и библиотека лежат в разных папках. Это может приводить к ошибке?

Comment: Нет, если эта папка указана в ключе -cp

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы JVM увидела эти файлы,они должны быть в classpath. Либо укажите их расположение в качестве аргумента для java/javac,либо положите в корень (где располагаются каталоги верхнего уровня с вашими классами).